# HTML5 to implement mobile app tabbar and titlebar

Tags: ios, html

I'm creating an iOS app with partially native code and partially html5. A splash screen followed by a webview, that's all for native code, the rest of the content are implemented by html5 and will be shown in the webview. In the webview, the page is divided to 3 parts, titlebar on the top, content in the middle and tabbar on the bottom. I want the titlebar and tabbar each stay in their position, that is the very top and the very bottom in the webview no matter how the user scrolls the page, the content is scrollable of course, now how can I achieve this? What I have so far is the following, but when keep scrolling until hit the very top/bottom there will be a white gap at the top of the titlebar or at the bottom of the tabbar, like most iOS app, how can I avoid this?

```
.mobile-titlebar {
    height: 44px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid @border-color;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.page-content {
    padding-top: 44px;
    padding-bottom: 49px;   /* Height of the footer element */
}
.mobile-tabbar {
    height: 49px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out by adding the following line in my iOS native code:

```
self.webview_main.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

Hope this helps someone.